# Log correlation id using Hangfire Filter

Tags: hangfire

I am trying to use the  [Hangfire Filter](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/extensibility/using-job-filters.html) and [ILogger.BeginScope](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/) to log the correlation id. The requirement is that each job execution will have its own correlation id so that it's easier to group the logs of the same job execution together if something happens.

My approach is that in `IServerFilter.OnPerforming` method, I first create a GUID, then using below code to begin the scope

```
logger.BeginScope(new FormattedDictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["CorrelationId"] = correlationId
            })
```

The subsequent log statements in the method `IServerFilter.OnPerforming` will have correlation id attached. But unfortunately, during job execution, the log statement won't have the correlation id scope. The `ILogger` instance of the job class is resolved using constructor. And the `ILogger` instance of the method `IServerFilter.OnPerforming` is resolved using a `IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService` method

I am wondering why so? And how can we fix this issue? I am open to other approaches of implementing logging correlation id as long as it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The reason being that when the local `IDisposable` in `IServerFilter.OnPerforming` created by a local `ILogger` instance are out of scope, since nothing reference it again, after a while, GC will collect it and thus the locally created scope will be lost. The solution is simple, using `AsyncLocal<ILogger>` instance on the filter to hold a reference to the created scope and only dispose it after the job finishes

Comment: How did you inject the logger?

Comment: I don't have the code anymore. I think I created one through `IServiceProvider` or something.

Comment: Okay, thanks, do you remember what type you used for ILogger<T>?

Comment: Sorry, cannot remember now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Serilog it can be done with FromLogContext

```
public sealed class SerilogJobCorrelationIdAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter
{
    private readonly ILog _logger = LogProvider.GetLogger(typeof(SerilogJobCorrelationIdAttribute));

    IDisposable? _logContext;

    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
        _logContext = LogContext.PushProperty("JobCorrelationId", filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id);
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            _logContext?.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            _logger.Warn($"An error occurred while trying to dispose the LogContext.\n{ex}");
        }            
    }        
}
```

Then register your filter in the startup

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new SerilogJobCorrelationIdAttribute(), order: 1);
```